# How to use the binding context for knockout js for partial pages in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

I am new to `knockoutjs`. I want to do validations for my text boxes using custom validations. But the `knockout js`  `viewmodel` is not defining. My procedure is I have a page called `MyProfile`. In `MyProfile` page there will be two tabs and each tab contains a partial page. I have defined the partial pages like this.

```
 @using MyApplication.Services.ViewModels
 @model MyProfileViewModel
   <div class="new-tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><span id="#personalsettings">Contact Info</span></li>
            <li><span href="#settings">Settings</span></li>               
        </ul>
        <div  id="user">
             <div class="row"> 
                     @{                      
                        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/User/_UserDetails.cshtml", Model.userViewModel);      
                      }
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="settings">
               <div>
                      @{
                         Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/User/_UserSettings.cshtml", Model.userSettingsViewModel);
                       }
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now in the two partial pages i have defined two binding's with the respective view models. And i am applying bindings in the two view pages. with the tab id element like

In the user page

```
   ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("user"));
   ko.applyBindings(userViewModel, document.getElementById("user"));
```

And in the settings page i have defined like

```
  ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("settings"));
  ko.applyBindings(userViewModel, document.getElementById("settings"));
```

But in the sources only one `viewmodel` getting the values properly. But the other `view model` is not defining. How can i solve this issue. Hope you understand my question. If i get the values in the second `viewModel` also i can do the validations.

Comment: are you trying to apply to different viewmodels to settings and users div?

Comment: @MyP3uK yes, I want to apply different view models for the two tabs

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste error since you're binding your userViewModel to the settings tab.  Is that correct?  If that's not the problem, please show your viewmodels and the associated HTML binding and explain which bindings are not working.

Comment: @PatrickSteele Its not copy/paste error. Its bit of huge code though. According to the above code will it work as i am defining two view models in two different pages and `applyingBinding` in the two partial pages.

Comment: Without seeing the javascript view models and the associated HTML, it will be difficult to determine why your bindings aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like right after you apply the bindings to the "user" div, you clear the bindings for it when applying them for settings div.

```
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("user")); // - try "settings" here instead of "user"
ko.applyBindings(userViewModel, document.getElementById("settings"));// - looks like you are applying userViewModel to the settings div here.
```

I have not seen in your code any reference to the settingsViewModel, I bet this is part of the problem as well.

Comment: sorry that's not the issue. I have updated the question. Check it once

Comment: You still bind settings div to the userViewModel though. You mentioned that you want to have two separate view models.

Comment: But the two viewModels are in two different pages. So what the problem might. I have given two different names though. For understanding i have given the small code here.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that instead of applying independent view models to each partial, compose your page view model with children view models for each tab.

```
function PageViewModel = function() {
    this.Tab1Model = new Tab1ViewModel();
    this.Tab2Model = new Tab2ViewModel();
}
```

Now in your html, you can apply the bindings like so:

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.Tab1Model">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial(/*Tab1...*/); }
</div>
<div data-bind="with: $root.Tab2Model">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial(/*Tab2...*/); }
</div>
```

And your apply binding would just be:

```
ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel());
```